# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker.huggingface' despite installing sagemaker package"

Tags: python, conda, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, huggingface

I am trying to use the `sagemaker.huggingface` module to run a hugging face estimator as described in [this blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/sagemaker-distributed-training-seq2seq#create-a-huggingface-estimator-and-start-training), but I encounter the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker.huggingface'; 'sagemaker' is not a package
```

This is the line of code it gets that error on, in the first line of my python file:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFace
```

I have installed the `sagemaker` package (version `2.213.0` when I run `conda list`) using `conda install sagemaker` without any errors on my system. If I do `import sagemaker`, I don't get the error. However, when I check if the `huggingface` submodule is included in the `sagemaker` package using the following code:

```py
if 'huggingface' in dir(sagemaker):
    print('The huggingface submodule is included in this version of sagemaker.')
else:
    print('The huggingface submodule is not included in this version of sagemaker.')
```

I get the output:

```
The huggingface submodule is not included in this version of sagemaker.
```

I am using Python 3.10.13 (when I check `python --version`) and have created a new conda environment named "distill" with the following packages installed:

```
conda create --name distill python=3.10.6 -y
conda activate distill
conda install -y pytorch==1.12.1 torchvision==0.13.1 torchaudio==0.12.1 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers@v4.24.0 datasets sentencepiece protobuf==3.20.* tensorboardX
```

I am running SageMaker Distribution 1.4 on SageMaker Studio.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to use the `sagemaker.huggingface` module?

Comment: when you actually get the exception, does it happen to be coming from file called `sagemaker.py` ? Also worth pointing out that a full stacktrace is way more helpful than just a copypaste of "I get this exception".

Comment: Problem solved! File was called sagemaker.py so it was calling itself.